# Spark Hive reporting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.Table.setTableName(Ljava/lang/String;)V

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am trying to use SparkSession to reading data from Hive.

my code:

> val warehouseLocation = "/user/xx/warehouse"
>
> val spark = SparkSession
>       .builder()
>      .master("local[*]")
>       .appName("HiveReceiver")
>      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir",warehouseLocation)
>       .enableHiveSupport()
>       .getOrCreate()
>
> import spark.sql
>
> sql("select * from sparktest.test").show()
>
> spark.stop()

my versions:

> spark:2.1.1
>
> hive:1.2.1
>
> hadoop:2.7.1

but there are some Exceptions when it run in IDEA:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.Table.setTableName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.MetastoreRelation.(MetastoreRelation.scala:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.lookupRelation(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionCatalog.lookupRelation(HiveSessionCatalog.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:457)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:479)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:464)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:307)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:464)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:454)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
>     at
>   scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:50)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:63)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:592)     at
>   com.bdp.steaming.HiveReceiver$.main(HiveReceiver.scala:24)    at
>   com.bdp.steaming.HiveReceiver.main(HiveReceiver.scala)

someone can tell where is the bug?

Comment: someone can tell me why? thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this question.In my case,there are two hive-metastore dependencies in my project,then i excluded a hive-metastore dependency.It worked.